# Promoting an event

Tags: discussion, support, scope, etiquette

I'm launching a series of meetups that focuses on a specific part of retrocomputing. However, Retrocomputing Stack Exchange doesn't have community ads, [the main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38597/the-bbs) seems quite inactive, and [the blog](https://retrocomputingblog.wordpress.com/) is dead.

Would it be appropriate to advertise the series in a post? If so, then on Main or Meta?

Note that this is not for profit; the series is entirely free and open to all.

Answer (score 4):

Such a post wouldn't be appropriate on the main site. We have had questions about meetups in the past and all have been closed and deleted.  This has been discussed before...
[Clubs/meetups: in scope?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/93/276)
and the consensus is that they are off-topic.

You are right that we don't have community ads, because we are still a beta site.  You could try putting community ads on other sites, but they may or may not be accepted.

Mentioning meetups in the chat room is definitely acceptable.  As you say, our chat room isn't very active but we do get a fair number of visitors to it, even if they don't say very much.  I would try it there.

As to whether you could post on meta, I would be inclined to say yes.  Other sites on StackExchange use their metas to post announcements about meetings or competitions, notably [Information Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/), so we could too.  As the mantra goes, "*meta is different*", you may be successful.

Comment: There's also a “schedule event in the chat room” thingy that makes it show up on the sidebar; would that be appropriate? (It's really meant for chat events, but…)

Comment: Yes, that could work.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Feel free to set up a recurring chat event that refers to [this](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1027/18114). (I cannot schedule events in the chat room, because I'm not a room owner.)

Comment: @Adám I found a better way than “schedule event in the chat room”; I can add entries to the “scheduled events” system on main (and meta, separately I think) directly, however it doesn't recur. As it's only every two weeks, the easiest automation would probably be you (or a bot of yours) bothering me at the end of each event to let me know to add the next one.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Wow, that's so nice of you. But… how does one find this event so one can register for it?

Comment: @Adám It's on the sidebar and links to your meta post.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 D'oh, only now did I see the "Upcoming Events" box. Nice!