# Introducing a new retrocomputing meetup: The APL Campfire

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

Due to [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language))'s age, it is [sometimes of interest to this community](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/search?q=apl).

Every fourth Sunday at 18:00 UTC, I'm hosting an event focusing on the history of APL programming, inviting participants to tell stories of their experiences. I figured this might be of interest to this audience, hence this advertisement. (Don't worry, no money involved!)

The next session is June 6th. Details at [apl.wiki/APL_Campfire](https://apl.wiki/APL_Campfire).

Comment: This looks great! One note: would it be possible to host the meeting on a more open platform than Zoom? Something like Jitsi Meet, perhaps? I don't know whether that kind of thing would affect whether people join _this_, but use of Zoom _has_ had an effect (negative – at least, if the vocal minority are any indication) on (network-wide) mod meeting turnouts.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I've tried Jitsi before, but the connection was markedly worse than Zoom. Secondly, and more importantly, the core target audience may, ironically, have issues with unfamiliar technology, while Zoom is quite universal by now. I'm recording locally on my machine. Thanks for your support and feedback.