# What are the rules about self promo on Meta?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I'm preparing a video showing the functioning of the MT-1804 (A 1980s Soviet bitslice processor system cloned from the 1970s AMD Am2900 Learning and Evaluation Kit), and putting it as the inaugural video of a YouTube channel in English dedicated to my collection of Soviet retro computers/microprocessors. What are the rules on this Meta chat for advertising such a channel? This is just the only place online where I know there might be an interested audience :-D

If it is forbidden, would a question about where it would be most effective to promote such a channel be alright on the main retrocomputing site?

Comment: Meta is in general way more relaxed, as it's about everything related which doesn't have to be a question at all. So go on, there is for sure one guy watching.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, [promotion on meta has been fine](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1027/278), so long as you meet our [self-promotion rules](/help/promotion):

> However, if you mention your product, website, etc. in your question or answer (or any other contribution to the site), you *must* disclose your affiliation in your post.

> **Don't talk about your product / website / book / job too much.**